# XPath help needed

Tags: c#, xpath

Given the following Xml:

```
<Animals xmlns="http://www.company.com/Global/US">
    <Mammals>
        <Animal>
            <Type>
                <Name>Cat</Name>
                <Breed>Ally Cat</Breed>
            </Type>
            <Color>
                <R>0</R>
                <G>0</G>
                <B>0</B>
            </Color>
        </Animal>
        <Animal>
            <Type>
                <Name>Dog</Name>    <-- I know this
                <Breed>Weimeraner</Breed>
            </Type>
            <Color>
                <R>190</R>    <- I need the value of this
                <G>190</G>
                <B>190</B>
            </Color>
        </Animal>
    <Mammals>
</Animals>
```

How can I get the integer value for the R node of Color given that I know the Name is "Dog"?

The following does not work for me.

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(xml);
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(_xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.company.com/Global/US");
var typeNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:Animals/ns:Mammals/ns:Animal/ns:Type/ns:Name[. = 'Dog']", nsm);
var r_val = typeNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.SelectSingleNode("/ns:Color/ns:R", nsm).InnerText;
```

typeNode in this code gives me the correct node, but then traversing to the grandparent node and selecting within that gives me null and therefore InnerText blows up.

Is there a better XPath expression I can use to get this?

This needs to be in c# 2.0 so unfortunately Linq and XDocument is not able to be supported.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (with `ns` prefix bound to `http://www.company.com/Global/US` namespace URI):

```
/ns:Animals/ns:Mammals/ns:Animal[ns:Type/ns:Name = 'Dog']/ns:Color/ns:R
```

Comment: Had to add the namespace in there like this, /ns:Animals/ns:Mammals/ns:Animal[ns:Type/ns:Name = 'Dog']/ns:Color/ns:R, but it worked. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing of C#, but this xpath expression should get you the correct node

```
//Animal[Type/Name = 'Dog']/Color/R
```